# Element of Website not inheriting color in smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css

My Website header is enclosed in a row set to blue background and yellow font color, the title, slogan and telephone number all render correctly in desktop mode but the phone number is not rendering color correctly in smaller screen sizes (appears a faded blue).
The title and slogan are within the hgroup but the telephone number has an element class of 'fonebanner'.
I've tried several variations of HTML and CSS script but to no avail, a mock-up of the site can be viewed [here](http://www.urbandreamscapes.com) - suggestions gratefully receieved.

```css
.row2 {
        background-color: #0000ff;
        color: #ffff00;
    }
    #header .fonebanner {
        clear: right;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    #header .fonebanner h2 {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 3em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 180px) and (max-width: 479px){
    #header .fonebanner {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
    #header .fonebanner h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row2">
      <header id="header">
        <div id="hgroup">
          <h1>ABC HTMLDESIGNS</h1>
          <h2>Catchy Slogan!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="fonebanner">
          <h2>01234 987654</h2>
        </div>..............
```

Comment: As an addendum - I've recently received notice from a friend who's got an Amazon Android device (mobile phone), that everything renders fine on that, so this may be a device specific problem.

Comment: Here's the quirk: Apple mobile devices will not display any numbers within my Website header element in any color other that blue. I've updated the index page of the site with a prefix of Tel: to the phone number which is displaying in yellow, but the number is blue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing brackets in your css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 180px) and (max-width: 479px)
    #header .fonebanner {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
    #header .fonebanner h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
```

should be

```
@media screen and (min-width: 180px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    #header .fonebanner {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
    #header .fonebanner h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }  }
```

Comment: My apologies! Ozgur, the brackets are in the CSS I missed them in the copy.

Comment: I see. And what do you mean by color not rendering correctly? Because it looks like it's working in sizes between 180px and 479px. and you only specify font-size attribute in `#header .fonebanner h2`

Comment: As I say it works fine in desktop mode, inheriting the style from row2, I reset the font-size in various @media screen to better suit the lower screen sizes. However a friend has mailed to say that it seems to operate OK on his Amazon Android device - so I'm stumped, I'll try the suggestion posted by Sagar..... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can add css code like following you can definetly apply your style in small screen. important force to take this style.

```
   @media screen and (min-width: 180px) and (max-width: 479px){
      #header, .row2{
       background-color:#fff !important;
      }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks! Sagar I'll give that a try, but it may currently be a quirk with certain devices..... see my reply to Ozgar